# What is the correct way to access a large fits grid in C with CFITSIO

Tags: c, fits

I have two fits grid which I am accessing with CFITSIO (https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/c). Now, the first grid is 1071 (row) x 3 (cols) and of the float data type. I can access this fine and print the output of each entry. When I repeat this code for my second grid (a large grid (1.1 Gb) which is 1071 x 262144 and also of the float data type, I get a Segmentation fault. Before I carry on, here's the code:

```
#FILE Cspec.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fitsio.h"
#include "load_data.h"
#include "general_functions.h"


#define MAX_ROW 230746
#define N 131072
#define WAVEMIN 450.0
#define WAVEMAX 650.0


void printerror( int status)
{
/*****************************************************/
/* Print out cfitsio error messages and exit program */
/*****************************************************/


if (status)
{
   fits_report_error(stderr, status); /* print error report */

   exit( status );   
}
return;
}



int main()
{   /*----------------------------
    Now load the table
----------------------------*/
printf("\n\n--------------------\nLoading the models..\n--------------------");
fflush(stdout);

// Imports and definitions
fitsfile *fptr;       /* pointer to the FITS file, defined in fitsio.h */
int status, anynull;
long naxes[2], fpixel, nbuffer, npixels, ii;
char filename[]  = "models.fits";     /* name of existing FITS file   */
status = 0;

// Open the file and kick off if its not there
if ( fits_open_file(&fptr, filename, READONLY, &status) )
    printerror( status );

/* read the NAXIS1 and NAXIS2 keyword to get image size */
//if ( fits_read_keys_lng(fptr, "NAXIS", 1, 2, naxes, &nfound, &status) )
//      printerror( status );

// Define the rows and columns of fits image and thus the buffer size
naxes[0] = 1017;
naxes[1] = 262144;
    size_t buffsize = ((size_t) (naxes[1] * naxes[0]) + (naxes[1] * sizeof(float)));
float nullval, buffer[buffsize];
npixels  = naxes[0] * naxes[1];         /* number of pixels in the image */
fpixel   = 1;
nullval  = 0;                /* don't check for null values in the image */

while (npixels > 0)
{
    nbuffer = npixels;
    if (npixels > buffsize)
    nbuffer = buffsize;     /* read as many pixels as will fit in buffer */

    if ( fits_read_img(fptr, TFLOAT, fpixel, nbuffer, &nullval,
      buffer, &anynull, &status) )
    printerror( status );

    for (ii = 0; ii < nbuffer; ii++)  
    {
        // Output the value
        printf("%f\t", buffer[ii]);
    }
    npixels -= nbuffer;    /* increment remaining number of pixels */
    fpixel  += nbuffer;    /* next pixel to be read in image */
}

if ( fits_close_file(fptr, &status) )
    printerror( status );

return 0;
}
```

I compile using:

```
nvcc Cspec2.c general_functions.c load_data.c -I/iraf/iraf/vendor/cfitsio  /iraf/iraf/vendor/cfitsio/libcfitsio.a  -lm -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

The other c files (general_functions.c and load_data.c) are not relevant. The reason for the last two flags comes from https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/c/f_user/node13.html which describe the size limits when working with fits files. One thing this says (para 4):

"If CFITSIO is compiled with the -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE and -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 flags on a platform that supports large files, then it can read and write FITS files that contain up to 2**31 2880-byte FITS records, or approximately 6 terabytes in size. It is still required that the value of the NAXISn and PCOUNT keywords in each extension be within the range of a signed 4-byte integer (max value = 2,147,483,648). Thus, each dimension of an image (given by the NAXISn keywords), the total width of a table (NAXIS1 keyword), the number of rows in a table (NAXIS2 keyword), and the total size of the variable-length array heap in binary tables (PCOUNT keyword) must be less than this limit."

I assumed that adding these flags would sort this out since 1071*262,144 = 280,756,224 which is below the range of a signed 4-byte integer (max value = 2,147,483,648). There is also more information here ( https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/c/c_user/node32.html ). Where am I going wrong? Why does this cause a seg fault? This code works fine with the smaller grid (1071*3). I assume I have to add some extra compiler flags or change something in my code? Could the problem lie in the fact I am using cfitsio from an IRAF distribution?

One thing I found from de-bugging is that I could not output the "buffsize" variable - this on it's own lead to a seg fault.

I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am using the nvcc compiler as I plan to offload some later work to the GPU. I'm still relatively new to C (from python).

Thanks

Sam